# I got "500 Internal Server Error" after performing Axios POST method after submitting a form on Laravel Project with React

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, axios

I'm working on a project using React as a front-end framework and Laravel as a back-end framework. While submitting a form, I got 500 error.

Here is the form code (**AddVaccineStock.js**)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import FormCard from "../../UI/FormCard/FormCard";

function AddVaccineStock(props) {
    const [medicine_id, setMedicineId] = useState(null);
    const [expiry_date, setExpiryDate] = useState(null);
    const [stock_amount, setStockAmount] = useState(null);

    let medId = props.match.params.id;

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(
                `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dashboard/vaccine_data/edit_vaccine/${medId}/add_vaccine_stock`
            )
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                setMedicineId(response.data.medicine_id);
            });
    }, []);

    // console.log(medicine_id);

    const addVaccineStock = async () => {
        const add = async (data) => {
            const addUrl = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dashboard/vaccine_data/edit_vaccine/${data.medicine_id}/add_vaccine_stock`;

            const res = await axios
                .post(addUrl, data)
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.data;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    return error;
                });

            return res;
        };

        const data = {
            medicine_id,
            expiry_date,
            stock_amount,
        };

        const res = await add(data);
        // console.log(data);
        // console.log(res);

        if (res.success) {
            alert(res.message);
        } else {
            alert(res.message);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="text-center mb-5">Tambah Stock Vaksin</h1>
            <FormCard
                form={
                    <form onSubmit={addVaccineStock}>
                        {/* <input type="hidden" value={medicine_id} /> */}
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Tanggal Kedaluwarsa</label>
                            <input
                                type="date"
                                className="form-control"
                                onChange={(event) =>
                                    setExpiryDate(event.target.value)
                                }
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Jumlah Stok</label>
                            <input
                                type="number"
                                className="form-control"
                                onChange={(event) =>
                                    setStockAmount(event.target.value)
                                }
                            />
                        </div>
                        <button className="btn btn-success">Simpan</button>
                    </form>
                }
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default AddVaccineStock;
```

Please note that the form that I submitted to the database has a foreign key, which is medicine_id from medicines table. The form that I want to submit is adding a vaccine stock, to the medicine_stocks table.

Here is the related controller (**MedicineStockController.php**):

Showing the form function

```
public function create($medicine_id)
{
    $medicine = Medicine::find($medicine_id);

    return $medicine;

    // return view('dashboard.dashboardPages.vaccineData.vaccineStockData.add_vaccine_stock');
}
```

Submitting the form function

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    
    $request->validate([
        'stock_amount' => 'required|integer',
        'expiry_date' => 'required|date'
    ]);

    try {
        $medicine_stock = MedicineStock::create([
            'medicine_id' => $request->input('medicine_id'),
            'stock_amount' => $request->input('stock_amount'),
            'expiry_date' => $request->input('expiry_date')

        ]);

        $response['message'] = 'Stock Obat/Vaksin berhasil ditambahkan!';
        $response['success'] = true;

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
        $response['success'] = false;
    }

    return $response;

}
```

Here is the related route in **api.php**:

```
Route::get('dashboard/vaccine_data/edit_vaccine/{medicine_id}/add_vaccine_stock', [MedicineStockController::class, "create"]);
Route::post('dashboard/vaccine_data/edit_vaccine/{medicine_id}/add_vaccine_stock', [MedicineStockController::class, "store"]);
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Any solutions and answers will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "*I got 500 error.*" - What, specifically, is your error? 500 generally means there's an issue with your code, but it could mean anything really. Check `storage/logs/laravel.log` (or `laravel-{date}.log`) for the actual error message.

Comment: does PHP have a log it sends errors to? perhaps that will tell you more (also, sometimes, in the browser developer tools you can view the response and see interesting information

Comment: @TimLewis It's weird that I can't open the Laravel.log file.
@JaromandaX How can I get the PHP error log? Here is the response in the browser `HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Date: Tue, 29 Jun 2021 14:16:46 GMT
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.3
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Tue, 29 Jun 2021 14:16:46 GMT
Content-Type: application/json

`

Comment: @JaromandaX The response.error returns this object: `{data: {…}, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}`

Comment: yeah, you're not showing the most interesting (useful) parts of the response ... like ... the BODY of theresponse

Comment: @JaromandaX Here is the response `HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Date: Wed, 30 Jun 2021 06:22:14 GMT
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.0.3
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Wed, 30 Jun 2021 06:22:14 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
`

Comment: so, no response body?

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't see anything on the response tab on the browser's console. Also, I can't expand that object I've posted before.

Comment: Guess you'll have to find the cause of the error by going through logs in the server - PHP logs errors, right?